# Use MPMoviePlayerController if iOS 7

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer

I have an app which uses the `AVplayerViewController` class and now I wish to support iOS 7. How can I use the `MPMoviePlayerController` instead if iOS 7 is running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in swift you can do it like this

```
if #available(iOS 8, *) {
    let player = AVplayerViewController()
} else {
    //fallback to MVMovie
}
```